# Why is my app crashing when I try to write to an external file?

Tags: android

In this activity, I am trying to save a string to an external file in response to a button being pressed. I have been using the other posts about writing to an external file but each one I try is crashing my app. I am also unsure if my AVD is the root of the issue and has the proper settings. Can someone take a look and see if there are any errors in my AVD settings or my activity file? Thank you in advance.

Here are my settings (not able to post images yet):

Device: 10.1" WXGA (Tablet) (1280 x 800 mdpi)

Target: Android 4.4.2-API Level 19

CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi-v7a)

Hardware keyboard present

Skin: Skin with dynamic hardware controls

Front Camera: Webcam0

Back Camera: Webcam0

Memory Options: Ram:512   VM Heap: 32

Internal Storage: 200 MiB

SD Card: Size: 200 MiB

Here is my activity's java file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FourthActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "MEDIA";
private TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_fourth);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fourth, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fourth,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

   /** Called when the user clicks an answer */

public void q1a1(){
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    tv.append("\nExternal file system root: "+root);

    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");

    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        pw.println("@string/q1a1");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "***** File not found. Did you" + "add a permission to the manifest?");
    }
    tv.append("\n\nFile written to "+file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(FourthActivity.this, FifthActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I believe my layout file is fine but I can add it if anyone would like to see it as well.

Here is the error log:

```
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     ... 11 more
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     at com.example.motorimagery.FourthActivity.q1a1(FourthActivity.java:75)
06-10 10:40:44.311: E/AndroidRuntime(4857):     ... 14 more
```

Here is the XML file:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="736dp"
    android:layout_height="226dp"
    android:text="@string/Question1"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:onClick="q1a1"
    android:text="@string/Q1A1" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Can you post error log

Comment: Do you have permission to write to a external storage?

Comment: I do have the permission statement in the manifest, Dimitri.

Comment: I made an edit to add the error log

Comment: What's on line 75 of **FourthActivity.java**? and can you post your **complete** xml layout, please?

Comment: Line 75:   tv.append("\nExternal file system root: "+root);

Comment: You never assign tv a value... Something like: `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);`

Comment: The </LinearLayout> didn't come up by the way. I'm getting an error saying myTextView cannot be resolved

Comment: Give your TextView an id: `android:id="@+id/myTextView"`

Comment: Obviously enough (?) you can use any other id than "myTextView" - just then find the very same in your Java code. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onClick Listener method signature is wrong: it misses the View parameter

```
public void q1a1(){
```

should be

```
public void q1a1(View v){
```

**[EDIT]**

By reading your new LogCat posting, it emerges that you never assign tv a value.
Something like:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

should be added after this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_fourth);
```

in your onCreate method

Comment: what if he was calling q1a1() function inside onClicklistener?? would it have been wrong?? just curious

Comment: Yes, the signature would have been: `public void onClick(View v)` - only the name changes. And it would have had the `@Overrides` modifier on top of it.

Comment: Adding View didn't help. Should I try that then?

Comment: I'm supposing you added something like this: `android:onClick="q1a1"` to some View (Button, TextView, ImageView, ... whatever clickable View). Try also adding explicitly `android:clickable="true"` to that View.

Comment: It still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: What's on line 75 of **FourthActivity.java**? and can you post your **complete** xml layout, please?

Comment: How do I fix my error with myTextView? It says it cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Give your TextView an id: `android:id="@+id/myTextView"`